# Perl SSH connection output issue

Tags: perl, shell, ssh

I'm executing multiple commands over ssh using the Net::SSH2 module.

#### My problem is the following:

Sometimes if I send the command I get no output back. The command is still executed I just don't get the response. Sometimes I get the response in the output of the next command I send.

I suspected that it tries to get the output before it appeared in the shell but then it should at least return the shell "welcome lines" (on shell startup) if its the first command but sometimes i get no output at all. At this point I just don't know what to try anymore.

#### I've tried

- to get the output multiple ways described in several forums for example from [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=569657) demo.
- Adding sleep between sending command and grabbing output. Helped somewhat most of the times but it still occurs. And having to determine the sleep time for each command individually is just not feasible. Especially since 1s seems to help on some occurences and doesn't help on others.
- Running the command multiple times, which results in the next command sometimes grabbing output from the previous command.
- Pushing until the last line of the output is a prompt with the same result: either ok or 0 lines.

#### My implementation

```
sub connectSSH{
    my $user = "...";
    my $password = "...";

    my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
    my $chan;
    if($ssh2->connect($ip,$port,Timeout => 10)){                        
        if(!$ssh2->auth_password($user, $password)){
            print"Error: Password wrong\n";
            exit;
        }else{
            $chan = $ssh2->channel();  # SSH
            $chan->blocking(0);
            $chan->shell();
        }
    }else{
        print "Connection to $ip not possible\n";
        exit;
    }
    return $chan;
}

sub sendCommand{
    my ($chan,$command) = @_;
    my @output=();
    
    print $chan "$command\n";
    #usleep(500)
    push(@output,"$_") while <$chan>;
    
    #process output...
}
```

I have to note that I've tried the usecases that didn't work with perl using python + paramiko and that seemed to have worked fine (didn't test as thorougly).

#### Update 26.08 (Partly solved)

I have retried (Thanks @jcaron for making me retry) **pushing until prompt appears** and that seems to work for most (the important) cases. Turns out that when I tried that method the first time there was another problem on top of the existing one, where I get no output from that specific host at all (not even after a delay/repeating the commands). Again with python/paramiko it works but not with my implementation in perl. However since the output from that specific group of hosts is not as important it's ok.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you set the channel to non-blocking? Also, is there any way you can actually detect the end of the output of a given command (or do you know the length/format of the output)? A better solution is probably to avoid using a single shell to execute all your commands (see comment [here](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SSH2-0.62/lib/Net/SSH2/Channel.pm#process_(_request,_message_)), but to execute the commands separately (one channel + one command for each).

Comment: @jcaron I've read somewhere that the flag should be set that way but setting to blocking doesn't change anything. I've tried detecting (updating post). I've tried avoiding shell as well. Also: I have to run a lot of commands and then it has to create a channel each time? Doesn't seem very efficient either. Might give it another go though, combining with sleeps.

Comment: Think of it like this: if you were connected to a shell, and copy-pasted a number of commands, how would you find out the output of each command? It's a pretty difficult job. Either create a script on the remote site that will run the commands and do whatever is needed with the output of each (probably piping or redirecting the output of each), or execute commands independently. Creating a channel is not the same as establishing a connection, it's a much lower cost operation, and it will enable you to get the output of each command separately.

Comment: @jcaron I get that it's difficult. What frustrates is that it works fine with python. Also after retrying without shell I remember why that didn't work. It's interactive only, exec is not supported (right out refused).Script on the remote end is not an option either. I hope I can find a solution for this. Really don't want to inline python just because of this issue. Thanks for trying though

Comment: I would be surprised you would get much of a difference with a different language it the underlying mechanisms are the same. Don't forget you could simply add `echo some_kind_of_unique_string-START` before each command and something similar after to act as markers of the output of each command.

Comment: @jcaron Updated the post. Most of my usecases work now (the others seem to have a different problem). Thanks again.

Comment: Did you try removing non-blocking mode? Are you doing the requests using perl and python from the same host? Would you not have some kind of issue with an improperly set up reverse DNS for instance?

Comment: @jcaron I did indeed. Same host. No idea what the problem is there. I'll try to figure that one out later.